# How to add SUBTOTAL to SUMPRODUCT with division formular in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, division, subtotal, sumproduct

Below are some raw data with related formular:

```
Col A1, A2 & A3: 4, 6 & 12 
Col B1, B2 & B3: 100, 150 & 120 
Formular: = SUMPRODUCT(B1:B3/A1:A3)
```

I tried to add SUBTOTAL function in front of the above formular when filtering use, but it doesn’t work......Can you help on this?

The combined SUMPRODUCT DIVISION plus SUBTOTAL formular is expected when filtering use.Thx!

Comment: *How* did you "tried to add SUBTOTAL function"?

Comment: = SUBTOTAL(9, SUMPRODUCT(B1:B3/A1:A3))

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Divisions in a Filtered List Using `AGGREGATE`

[image]

**Formula**

```
=LET(n,B5:B7,d,A5:A7,
    v,BYROW(d,LAMBDA(r,AGGREGATE(2,5,r))),
SUM(n/d*v))
```

The 1st `BYROW` parameter can be either column. I opted for the divisor having in mind division by zero.

**Variables**

```
n - Numerator or Dividend
d - Denominator or Divisor
v - Visibility (1 or 0)
```

**Legacy Excel**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(B5,ROW(B5:B7)-ROW(B5),))/A5:A7)
```

Comment: Hi, for ‘r’ & ‘s’ variables, what should I input as?

Comment: It's a Microsoft 365 formula. The only thing you need to modify are the range references in the first row of the formula. I've added a formula for older Excel versions to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. The `s` should have been a `v`. Corrected. The `r` variable is a variable used by the `BYROW` function representing each row of the supplied 1st parameter `d`.